# Partition unused space larger when mounted vs unmounted in GParted

Tags: gparted, ext4

Trying to resize partition using GParted to make it as small as possible before creating read-only image.

When mounted, unused space is 2.06GiB… when unmounted (right-clicking partition in GParted and selecting “Unmount”), it is 1.1GiB.

Why and how can I shrink 2.06GiB of unused space?

### Mounted

[image: Mounted]

### Unmounted

[image: Unmounted]

Comment: How do you (un)mount? Where do you see these sizes? Screenshots would help.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for feedback… please see updated question.

Comment: I'm not sure that the information is correct when the disk is unmounted. I don't see where it would be getting it from.

Comment: @harrymc The underlying issue I am trying to solve is that I have two separate installs of Ubuntu… one taking up 8.01GiB and another 8.02GiB. When I create images of both, one is considerably larger than the other. Discrepancy appears to be related to issue presented in this question.

Comment: Ran `zerofree` on both, same issue…